# Telethon как у entity определить канал это или группа и могу ли я в ней писать?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

При получении списка всех диалогов Telethon делит их на три типа channel, chat, user как я могу определить что это за диалог канал или группа и как определить могу ли я в них писать, например если я забанен в группе?

Answer (score 0):

Ответа на библиотеке telethon мне найти не удалось, но ещё немного постаравшись, мне удалось найти решение на библиотеке pyrogram, код ниже выведет вам тип диалога, диалоги в которых можно писать сообщения, идут под типом ChatType.GROUP и ChatType.SUPERGROUP:

```
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client

api_id = api_id
api_hash = 'api_hash'


app = Client("account", api_id, api_hash)
app.start()


async def get_dialog():
    async for dialog in app.get_dialogs():
        print(dialog.chat.type)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(get_dialog())
```

Answer (score 0):

Думаю уже ответ не актуален, но возможно поможет тем, кто только наткнулся на эту проблему. С обновлением библиотеки, определить **ТОЧНЫЙ** тип диалога - нельзя, но можно понять, пользователь или группа/канал, делает это просто:

```
async def main():
    await client.start()
    async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
      print(f'type - {dialog.is_user}')
```